# Options disappeared from the project's application properties on Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I don't remember doing anything that might have caused it. After i reopened the solution the options had disappeared. And also all my forms' buttons have become flat.

**Before**
[image: before]

**After**
[image: after]

Comment: Looks like a broken machine problem to me.  First reboot.  Then check if it still works on a new app.  Then checkout an older working version of the project from source control.

Comment: I've tried all of those. The older version works as it should. But that's not the solution because i've done a plenty of work since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chek Application.myapp file within "My Project" folder of your application. Usually it is caused by invalid xml tags.

Often git merge conflict causes this file to be invalid. Just open and resolve the conflict and restart the visual studio.